# Paperclip running multiple times on each page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip to save photos to my users' profiles. Rails is saving the paperclip attachments multiple times every time a page loads. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: [paperclip] Saving attachments.

Comment: You really need to include some of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like User object is updated every time the page loads. This can happen if you are recording last_login_time for the user. The paperclip does not save the file every time. It prints the trace messages during save. Even though it is annoying, it is mostly harmless.